# need Help for table creation wirh regex in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to create a table in Oracle whose structure is defined below:

legalMemberBic -Data necessarily informed
Character string respecting the following regular expression: [AZ] {6,6} [A-Z2-9] [A-NP-Z0-9] [A-Z0-9] {3,3}

I am stuck in table creation as I dont know how to use this regex when defining the table structure. In other words, how to use this regex along with create command.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately I don't quite understand your question. Please review the [How to ask section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center and edit your question to include a better problem description and maybe the code that is failing or you would like to see working.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like :

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_CODES
(
  l_name    VARCHAR2(30), 
  p_code    VARCHAR2(30)
    CONSTRAINT p_code_format      
      CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE ( p_code, ' [AZ] {6,6} [A-Z2-9] [A-NP-Z0-9] [A-Z0-9] {3,3}' ) )
);
```